# I'm looking program for vector based animation/video

Tags: software-recommendation, video, graphics, inkscape

I want to create a video. The idea is to make a large (fixed) image where camera is flying above. I am familiar with Inkscape so I would prefer to make the image with it.

I need a program to move the camera across the image and save it to a video file. Alternatively I need another program to create and animate the video.

Does somebody have an idea? A couple of years ago I worked with Fireworks, but I don't have a Windows system or a Fireworks license here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about Blender? http://www.blender.org/

Comment: That is a very good idea. I'll create that image with Inkscape an move the camera with Blender. Thank you!

Comment: @SvenWalter: LOL - why didn't you say 3D was fine? (Glad you found your solution, I was going to suggest blender if you wanted something 3D...)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think about 3D. I knew Blender before, but I didn't had the idea to make my animation therewith.

Answer (score 5):

Try [synfig](http://packages.ubuntu.com/synfig) [image: Install synfig] studio. It's similar in some ways to Inkscape, and geared toward vector based animation.

Screenshot:

> [image: Synfig Studio]

The interface is obviously a bit confusing at first (even overwhelming), but fortunately in the help menu there are tutorials and more to get you going.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is a good program for 2D animations, but I think it don't fit my needs.